# Problem with installing Java: java: command not found

Tags: mac, macos, java

I just installed Java 8.25 but I'm still not getting 'legacy' applications to work. I tried verifying the version in terminal:

```
manfred$ java --version
-bash: java: command not found
```

I think there's a conflict between two versions or something perhaps. How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you install Java?

Comment: @Mark the .dmg with installer.

Comment: which dmg? Oracles JRE, or JDK etc

Comment: @Mark First I did the Oracle JRE 8.25 and then the JDK 8.25...

Comment: As per my answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112533/237) Oracles's OS X  JRE does not install /usr/bin/java. I would reinstall the JDK and check what is in /usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Java is not in the path.  I do something like this in my ~/.bash_profile

```
# Get Java Home for the specific version
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8 2>/dev/null`
# Add Java to the path
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Quit terminal once you create or edit ~/.bash_profile.  FYI if you are creating ~/.bash_profile make sure you give it executable privileges.

Comment: ~/.bash_profile does not need executable privileges

Comment: Interesting all these years I have been making sure my bash start up scripts have execute privilege.  Good to know that is not needed.